# Make new tabs appear from left to right, to the right of the parent, in Chrome

Tags: chrome, tabs

I'd like to make Chrome a bit smarter, or at least a bit more convenient, regarding the position of new tabs.

For a long time, the behavior of Chrome was ok, if not always ideal. When opening a page in a new tab starting from a tab T₀ (e.g. with a middle click on a link), the new tab would appear to the right of the last tab T₁ previously opened from T₀, or immediately to the right of T₀ itself if I hadn't opened a tab from T₀ yet. Closing T₁ or moving T₁ to another window would reset the new tab position to T₀, even though I would prefer to maintain the new tab position as the rightmost position in the tab tree from T₀. If I moved T₁ inside the same window and then opened a new tab T₂ from T₀, then T₂ would still end up to the right of T₁, which is again what I wanted.

Recently — I think since I upgraded from 41.x to 42.0.2311.90 (stable channel) — the behavior when opening tabs has changed. I haven't figured out how tab positioning works, but often (not always), the new tab ends up immediately to the right of T₀.

For example, when middle-clicking three links in T₀, I used to end up with

```
T₀ T₁ T₂ T₃
```

Now this sometimes happens, but often I end up with

```
T₀ T₃ T₂ T₁
```

How can I get the previous behavior back, or something close enough? In particular:

- If I open several tabs from T₀, they should appear from left to right in the order of opening.
- If I had two tabs T₀ T' and I open a tab from T₀, the new tab should appear to the left of T'.
- If I close a tab and undo the closure (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), the new tab should appear in its previous position.

I suspect there's an extension that does what I want, but I can't find an obvious one.

Comment: Similar behavior described [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=461985)... maybe it's the same bug...

Comment: @don_crissti Maybe, thanks, though I've also observed this with non-pinned T₀.